# What is Vb.net equivalent of 1.0e-5 in C++?

Tags: c++, vb.net, visual-c++

I have a C++ program , a line from it in macro definitions says

```
#define U_MIN 1.0e-5
#define U_MAX 1.0e5
```

If I wish to convert this code in Vb.net language what is the equivalent?

Comment: A quick Google search yielded [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deszhz3d%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`e` is exponent notation...

```
1.0e-5 = 1.0 x 10 ^ -5 = 0.00001
1.0e5 = 1.0 x 10 ^ 5 = 100000
```

so..

```
Const U_MIN As Double = 0.00001
Const U_MAX As Double = 100000
```

Note that Visual Studio actually lets you use exponent notation, so you can type

```
Const U_MIN As Double = 1e-5
```

and it will expand it for you..